# How to programmatically select an input type="time" field on the minute value?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, time

I'm selecting the input element like so:

```
document.querySelector('#time').focus();
```

But this always selects the hour portion of the field's value:

[image: asdad]

How can I select the minute portion like so?:

[image: adasdasd]

Comment: what browser you tried?

Comment: I don't think there's a standard way to do this. The input doesn't even have to be formatted with multiple fields like this, it could be a clock face.

Comment: this is on both the latest chrome and firefox

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701658/is-there-any-way-to-focus-on-a-specific-unit-within-a-datetime-local-input-contr and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62514091/focus-minutes-part-of-time-input-using-javascript but essentially unsolved

Comment: @Sphinx What exactly did you try? You were able, via JavaScript, to focus on the *minutes* of a time input?